# How to wget a file from Nexus components?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, wget, nexus3

I want to get a .war file from Nexus to put it on a Tomcat. But I don't succeed to wget a file from Nexus 3.2 ... Many questions resolved with 2.x but not for 3.2.

Or if you have another method to deploy a .war file from Nexus to Tomcat ... =)

[File that I want to wget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prl5u.png)

Answer (score 0):

It was really simple. I just need to right click on the red circle like on the screenshot and copy link adress.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2NRO.png)